# Translation is inaccurate n orthogonal view

Tags: opengl

[image]

Attached to this posting is an image displayed by OpenGl. The image is displaying (in orthogonal view) some white cubes made from polygons (each cube is made by two triangles).

The alike cubes are instanced and thus share an original copy of the mesh, individual positioning (xy axes) is applied to each instance, giving me the cubes as in the image. In addition, the positioning data is of type float and rounded at two decimal places to stop rounding error during cumulative math additions. After manually verifying the x-axis position values with those used by the cubes, they are exactly at 0.11 away from each other like so: 0.06, 0.17, 0.28, 0.39, 0.50, 0.61, 0.72, 0.83, 0.94, 1.05 (x-axis data used by top row).

After screen capturing the image from OpenGl and zooming to pixel level, confires the noticeable differences in spacing between the columns, which are 1 to 3 pixels. The more scaled down the arrangement of the white cubes is in OpenGl, more pronounced the differences are noticeable, which dose not look so great visually.

Now my question is, why is the spacing between the cubes changing, even though the spacing between the cubes is exactly 0.11 units apart, for the same instance of the mesh? I need the spacing to be equally the same between each column of cubes, is there a way to fix this or an alternative solution?

Note: It appears to me, from studying the image, that the translations for spacing are correct, however the cubes do not appear to be drawing correctly, otherwise the alignment would not be lining up at consecutive sequence of columns...

Comment: To me, this looks like sampling artifacts you totally should expect. You simply can't draw with subpixel precision. If you want pixel-perfect cubes and spacings, you mast draw them in the correct size and distance depending of the window size.

Comment: @derhass Wonderful idea! I have been having issues with this many times in the past with polygons alignment, but now i understand what you mean. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @derhass How would i calculate the "correct size and distance depending of the window size"? Is the "correct size" in this case mesured in pixels based on the "window size" ratio or in [-1,1] coordinates, and than the objects move away from the screen?

Comment: Well, what matters are the final window space coordiantes of your primitives. You sould draw in such a way that the primitives actually fill whole pixels, so that the edges of your primitives alwyas lie on bondaries between the pixels. How you get there with your input coordinates is just a metter of how you have your transformations set up.

Comment: Considering the[-1,1] normalized device space, when your viewport is `w` pixels wide, a single pixel will be `2/w` units wide there, and -1 denotes the left _edge_ of the leftmost pixel, while 1 denotes the right _edge_ of the rightmost pixel. So to draw a `n` pixel wide square starting at pixel `x` (x as some integer in 0 ... w-1), you will need to draw from `-1+2*x/w` to `-1+2*(x+n)/w` to stay exactly at the pixel edges. You can make life easier if you just set up some pixel-exact ortho transform, but in the end, it will not matter.

Comment: @derhass Okey, in that case i have some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably just an aliasing issue.  Ultimately, your floating point object coordinates are projected into integer pixel coordinates.  If they are in between, they are rounded one way or another, leading the issues like you are seeing here.